# Disable user-specific background programs/services

Tags: macos

On Mac OS X/OS X/macOS, there are some programs or services that run in the background and they usually have an icon up in the menu bar on the right. One example is Dropbox and another is VMware Fusion. My account runs slower than the others on this computer and I'm pretty sure it's because various background services/programs do not run on the other accounts. I do not see any item in the System Preferences program that allows me to switch these off. How do I switch them off? Is there a file in `~/Library` that controls these things?

Comment: What does activity monitor show.?

Comment: @Mark How is that going to help?

Comment: It will show what processes are slowing the machine down or if you are running out of memory. That is don't guess what is happening but measure it.